# How do I access getToken in

Tags: express-jwt

In the [express-jwt docs](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) there is a reference to being able to use a getToken function to get the token from a request.

How do you use this call in a route?

```
app.use(jwt({
  secret: 'hello world !',
  credentialsRequired: false,
  getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
  }
}));
```

Comment: please let us know whether our answers helped solve your problem or point you in the correct direction, as we would like to ensure our answers are constructive and beneficial to users of the community as well as yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A useful little trick is to add `unless` which makes every URL except those specified by unless require a token.

This means you don't need to create a `app.get` for every single path in your api that you want to protect (unless you want different secrets for each, which I don't know why you would).

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var expressJWT = require('express-jwt');

app.use(
  expressJWT({
    secret: 'hello world !',
    getToken: function fromHeaderOrQueryString (req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer')
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        else if (req.query && req.query.token)
            return req.query.token;

        return null;
    }
  }).unless({ path: ['/login'] }));

// Test paths
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
   res.send("Attempting to login.");
});

app.get('/otherurl', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Cannot get here.');
});
```

Or you simply specify it for a single path:

```
app.get('/protected',
   expressJWT({
     secret: 'hello world !',
     getToken: function fromHeaderOrQueryString (req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer')
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        else if (req.query && req.query.token)
            return req.query.token;

        return null;
      }
 }));
```

Notice the change from `get` and `use` in the configuration.

For every path that you supply through `express-jwt`, the function `getToken` is run if specified in your configuration.

What's nice about adding `unless` is that now you have minimized the amount of work you need to do in order to get the token from the user for each and every path.

Refer to [index.js](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/blob/98867945814ded65055104253ac5742a7622e64f/lib/index.js) of `express-jwt` which tells you more about how `getToken` works:

- If you specify the option as a function, the token value is the returned value of the function

  - This means that you can supply custom logic for handling your tokens, and may be a useful place to call `verify`.
- Otherwise it runs the standard logic for extracting the token from the Authorization header with the format of '[Authorization Bearer] [token]' (I denote the brackets to show where it splits the string).

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
app.get('/protected',
  jwt({
    secret: 'hello world !',
    credentialsRequired: false,
    getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring(req) {
      if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
        return req.query.token;
      }
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```

Just add the `getToken` field in the object you pass to the jwt middleware. It's a combination of the example in the question, and the first example in the [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#usage).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get a JWT and Bearer tokens is:

To get a JWT token

```
let token = req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.match(/^JWT (.*)$/);
if (token && token[1]) { token = token[1]; }
if (!token) { throw ['missingRequired']; }
```

To get a Bearer token

```
let token = req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.match(/^Bearer (.*)$/);
if (token && token[1]) { token = token[1]; }
if (!token) { throw ['missingRequired']; }
```

To support both types of tokens:

```
let token = req.headers.authorization
  && (
    req.headers.authorization.match(/^JWT (.*)$/)
    || 
    req.headers.authorization.match(/^Bearer (.*)$/)
  );
if (token && token[1]) { token = token[1]; }
if (!token) { throw ['missingRequired']; }
```